# Visual Studio doesn't format document with List initialization

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I instantiate a List like this:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
   "foo" ,
   "bar",                "toto"
};
```

I expected using the code formatting functionality of Visual Studio I could get a result like this one :

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
   "foo",
   "bar",                
   "toto"
};
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea if it's possible o fix it ?

Thanx

Comment: In what order did you type that? What if you remove and re-add the `;`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Removing or adding `;` doesn't change anything I type the code as you can read it inserting some space to illustrate.

Comment: @Tidus972, where did you type that code?

Comment: Related? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/625182/visual-studio-refuses-to-auto-format-array-initializer-expressions-that-span-multiple-lines

Comment: Yes, this is it ! When I put everything on one Line, it removes correctly the extra space but does not go to the next line. I suppose it still not implemented.
So should I put this question as resolved even if the response is just it's not possible with the current version of VS 2017 ?

Comment: Okay, so a known 'bug' then.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't have such collection initializer formatting rule and EditorConfig doesn't either (see [.NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference) article on MSDN). To apply custom formatting to existing code you can use regular expression and [Find and Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text) Visual Studio feature.

[image: Visual Studio Options]

Comment: This work fine for an object, not for a List of object.

Comment: Yes, because there is a rule for object initializer (Place members in object initializers on new line) but there isn't one for collection initializer. They are different things, see [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) article on MSDN